# log declard variable content angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, http, variables

I have a declared variable called currentUser which contain a user object coming from http get request, I want just to log the currentUser variable but I got undefined ! can some one explain why please !

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';    
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUser: any;
  user: FormGroup;
  cities: any[];
  fileToUpload: any;
  avatarPath: any;
  avatarURL: any;
  returnUrl: any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private fb:FormBuilder
  ) {
   this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('api/user').subscribe(user => {
      this.currentUser = user;
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
    });
    console.log('this.currentuser :', this.currentUser)    
    this.http.get('api/cities').subscribe((cities: any[]) => {
      this.cities = cities;
    });
    this.user.patchValue({
      firstName: this.currentUser.firstName,
      lastName: this.currentUser.lastName,
      email: this.currentUser.email,
      profession: this.currentUser.profession,
      gender: this.currentUser.gender,
      birthDate: this.currentUser.birthDate,
      phone: this.currentUser.phone,
      oldPassword: this.currentUser.oldPassword,
      password: this.currentUser.newPassword,
      address: this.currentUser.address,
      postalCode: this.currentUser.postalCode,
      city: this.currentUser.city._id
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to write full url to your API? For example: localhost:4200/api/users ?

Comment: when subscribe user is coming and logged successfully, what I do not understand is my variable currentUser won't be logged !!

Comment: The order of events for the first 4 lines of `OnInit` are: API request fired, `console.log` called, value assigned to `currentUser`, `localStorage.setItem` called. Since the value is assigned after it is logged, the logged value is correctly output as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens because of sync. Try this:

```
this.http.get('api/user').subscribe(user => {
    this.currentUser = user;
    console.log('this.currentuser :', this.currentUser);
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
});
```

Comment: yes that works , but why this.currentUser is undefined outside the http get request ?

Comment: When you send a request to get some data, javascript DOES NOT wait for ending of the request, it pushes it into a stack and continue executing script. There is a good things in JS, it calls "callbacks" You also can make an async request using Promises